# SQL Query to extract data from a field and return counts instead of text, then group with totals

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two-column table called Billing which looks like this:

```
ID                                      Details
E4A02FB2-298B-4790-B01A-DCAE2B3CC0A2    {"Search":"Tint","Subject":"JAY PATEL","SubjectId":"35","SLW":"True","MN":"False","EPP":"False","ApproximateTotalRecords":"0"}
164AD558-E3AF-4FB9-9CCF-3EB8FE7A02FE    {"Search":"Tint","Subject":"Derel Borges","SubjectId":"TL-100317-9A3TG-FS-001","SLW":"True","MN":"True","EPP":"True","ApproximateTotalRecords":"0"}
95133974-A169-4647-B176-E9F3CF1FFE26    {"Search":"Tint","Subject":"KRISTEN KiFL","SubjectId":"25517489","SLW":"True","MN":"False","EPP":"False","ApproximateTotalRecords":"0"}
E4A02FB2-298B-4790-B01A-DCAE2B3CC0A2    {"Search":"Tint","Subject":"ASHLEY HARMN","SubjectId":"35","SLW":"True","MN":"False","EPP":"False","ApproximateTotalRecords":"0"}
E4A02FB2-298B-4790-B01A-DCAE2B3CC0A2    {"Search":"Tint","Subject":"ZACHARY PRIDGEN","SubjectId":"35","SLW":"True","MN":"False","EPP":"False","ApproximateTotalRecords":"0"}
95133974-A169-4647-B176-E9F3CF1FFE26    {"Search":"Tint","Subject":"GODFREY CREELEY","SubjectId":"27235440","SLW":"True","MN":"False","EPP (temp)":"False","ApproximateTotalRecords":"0"}
E4A02FB2-298B-4790-B01A-DCAE2B3CC0A2    {"Search":"Tint","Subject":"FELICIA SMITH","SubjectId":"35","SLW":"True","MN":"False","EPP (temp)":"False","ApproximateTotalRecords":"0"}
E4A02FB2-298B-4790-B01A-DCAE2B3CC0A2    {"Search":"Tint","Subject":"KIANA JOHN","SubjectId":"35","ApproximateTotalRecords":"0"}
E4A02FB2-298B-4790-B01A-DCAE2B3CC0A2    {"Search":"Tint","Subject":"HU LI","SubjectId":"35","SLW":"True","MN":"False","EPP (temp)":"False","ApproximateTotalRecords":"0"}
95133974-A169-4647-B176-E9F3CF1FFE26    {"Search":"Tint","Subject":"PAT REID","SubjectId":"26134607","SLW":"True","MN":"False","EPP (temp)":"False","ApproximateTotalRecords":"0"}
E4A02FB2-298B-4790-B01A-DCAE2B3CC0A2    {"Search":"Tint","Subject":"JOHN RODRIGUEZ","SubjectId":"35","SLW":"True","MN":"False","EPP":"False","ApproximateTotalRecords":"0"}
95133974-A169-4647-B176-E9F3CF1FFE26    {"Search":"Tint","Subject":"FAWN JOSEY","SubjectId":"27108394","SLW":"True","MN":"False","EPP (temp)":"False","ApproximateTotalRecords":"0"}
E4A02FB2-298B-4790-B01A-DCAE2B3CC0A2    {"Search":"Tint","Subject":"OSCAR DELL","SubjectId":"35","SLW":"True","MN":"False","EPP (temp)":"False","ApproximateTotalRecords":"3"}
E4A02FB2-298B-4790-B01A-DCAE2B3CC0A2    {"Search":"Tint","Subject":"SARAH SMITH","SubjectId":"35","SLW":"True","MN":"False","EPP":"False","ApproximateTotalRecords":"0"}
164AD558-E3AF-4FB9-9CCF-3EB8FE7A02FE    {"Search":"Tint","Subject":"KELLER SMITH","SubjectId":"35","SLW":"True","MN":"False","EPP":"False","ApproximateTotalRecords":"0"}
```

What I need to accomplish is to write a query that extracts the number of True SLW, MN, EPP, and EPP (temp) from each record and then returns them as a count, by ID.

So for ease of understanding, let me show the desired results in two steps:

The query would first need to accomplish this: Please pardon the image as I was not able to get the table to line up properly for reading purposes:
[image]

Note that not all 4 of the codes exist in every record.  If the code doesn't exist, I'd still want it returned as a zero for that row.

And after this, I'd want the total by ID - so the final results of this query would look like this:

```
ID                                      SLW MN  EPP EPP (temp)
E4A02FB2-298B-4790-B01A-DCAE2B3CC0A2    8   0   0   0
164AD558-E3AF-4FB9-9CCF-3EB8FE7A02FE    2   1   1   0
95133974-A169-4647-B176-E9F3CF1FFE26    4   0   0   0
```

This is very advanced for my level of SQL query experience, so hoping someone here can help guide me in the right direction?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
SELECT
    ID
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Details LIKE '%"SLW":"True"%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) SLW
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Details LIKE '%"MN":"True"%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) MN
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Details LIKE '%"EPP":"True"%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) EPP
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Details LIKE '%"EPP (temp)":"True"%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [EPP (temp)]
FROM Billing
GROUP BY ID
```

And for the more basic result set:

```
SELECT
    ID
    , CASE WHEN Details LIKE '%"SLW":"True"%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END SLW
    , CASE WHEN Details LIKE '%"MN":"True"%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END MN
    , CASE WHEN Details LIKE '%"EPP":"True"%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END EPP
    , CASE WHEN Details LIKE '%"EPP (temp)":"True"%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [EPP (temp)]
FROM Billing
```

Comment: Chris, that works perfectly.  Thanks for this and this is great for me to learn the SUM(CASE) syntax.  Thanks again.